# How to retrieve row values on behave of column distinct value in SQLite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, distinct

I have a table like this

```
  User-ID     RANK        Dept     LEVEL-PASSED         
 -------     ------       -----     --------  
    1          950         TECH        54
    2          525         TECH        32
    3          379         TECH        23
    4          955         AGRI        54
    5          956         AGRI        54
    6          558         AGRI        32
```

On behalf of distinct values in column "level passed" , i want to retrieve the Dept Value with it.

How can i do it in sq-lite android.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] { LEVEL-PASSED}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

This retrieves distinct level passed values i.e 54,32,23 but with it i also want to retrieve dept values.

expected result would be like this.

```
Dept     LEVEL-PASSED 
TECH        54
TECH        32
TECH        23
```

I do not care if Dept has TECH or AGRI. The distinct should just bring some dept value with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite allows in the select list non aggregated columns when you `group by ...`, so use this *feature* since you don't care which department will be returned:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select dept, [level-passed] from " + TABLE_NAME + " group by [level-passed]", null);
```

Or use `MAX()` or `MIN()` to aggregate if you want standard SQL:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select max(dept) dept, [level-passed] from " + TABLE_NAME + " group by [level-passed]", null);
```